# Time synchronisation in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 2 measurement series. Both are constructed with time and with the corresponding value. The time and value data are 1 variable with format <6800x1 double>. The time in the first series is structured as follows: 0s, 0.1s, 0.2s... . The time in the second series is structured as follows: 0s, 0.123s, 0.212s, 0,345s,... . How can i synchronis and plot both series in matlab? They start at the same time.

Comment: Do you already have the time vectors? ie a vector `[0 0.1 0.2 ...]` and another one with `[0 0.123 0.212 0.345 ...]` ?

Comment: Yes, 4 vectors. 2 time vectors und 2 value vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [plot](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) them with x and y arguments:

If you already have the time vectors (I assume you'd call them t1 and t2, data vectors respectively x1 and x2)

```
plot(t1,x1,t2,x2)
```

Matlab will plot these two series, ie: it will plot the points `[ (t1(1), x1(1)) ; (t1(2),x1(2)) ; ...]` and likewise for the 2nd series. It doesn't matter whether the data in `t2` is periodically, matlab only looks at the values themselves and puts a datapoint on the figure correspondingly.

otherwise, find a way to construct them. If you have a fixed sampling frequency (your first series seems to be at 10Hz):

```
t1=0.1*(0:(numel(x1)-1));
```

for the 2nd series, I can't see any period in there.

Comment: The first already has a 10Hz period and the second dosnt is periodically. That's my problem? Or plot matlab automatically synchronis with this function plot(t1,x1,t2,x2)?

Comment: If you'd tested this out for yourself, you'd already knew that the answer is yes!

Comment: Okay. I get the data yet, and wanted to ask first before.